# How to search LDAP Global Catalog by domain netbios name and user login

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have the AD Global Catalog configured. There are several domains in catalog. How can I find users from domain with specific netbiosname and login?

Comment: check this and give a try https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

•   You can search AD users with a specific netbios name and login (samaccount name) through powershell query. Also, the user principal name attribute is denoted as ‘msDS-PrincipalName’ in ADSI attribute. Therefore, the format of ‘ABC\login.name’ has the ‘ABC’ as the netbios name of the domain that is to be searched in the global catalog.

•   Therefore, you can use a powershell query to search a particular user in this format and get this output as desired. Please find the below powershell query for your reference: -

```
 ‘ Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*SvcAccount"' | Format-Table Name,SamAccountName -A ‘
```

Output: -
Name             SamAccountName

---

SQL01 SvcAccount SQL01
SQL02 SvcAccount SQL02
IIS01 SvcAccount IIS01

•   In the above query, you can add the ‘netbiosdomainname\samaccountname’ of the concerned user in the filter parameter and get the desired output from the global catalog. Please find the below link for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps

Comment: Unfortunately I have no netbios names when executing this query, the only user names are in both columns

Comment: Netbios names are nothing but the domain name without '.com' or '.in' suffixes. You can get the netbios name through this powershell cmd. But before running this command, please ensure that Active directory module is installed in powershell and you are running this cmd with elevated domain administrator privileges: - (Get-ADDomain -Server servername.domainname.com).NetBIOSName